# translating a text to different languages using php

Tags: php, wordpress, multilingual, wpml

Basically, I am trying to translate a few texts to Chinese from the default language french. The following code states the translation from one language to another language but I am confused with the part of having the text translated to more than one language in PHP. Any help would be appreciated

```
<?php
$icl = ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE;
$placeholder = $icl == 'fr' ? 'Sélectionner une filiale' : 'Select an affiliate';
$all = $icl == 'fr' ? 'Toutes les filiales' : 'All affiliates';
$filter = $icl == 'fr' ? 'Filtrer les offres' : 'Filter offers';
?>
```

Comment: If you need to switch between more than two alternatives, then using the ternary operator `?` makes rather less sense - sure, that could be nested over multiple “levels”, but that gets ugly fast. Put your text strings in an array instead, and use the language code as key on the top level, so that you can find the proper text version that way. Something like this, `$translations['en']['placeholder'] = 'Select an affiliate'; $translations['fr']['placeholder'] = 'Sélectionner une filiale';` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this, even if **this is not good coding**:

```
<?php
$icl = ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE;
switch ($icl) {
    case 'fr':
        $placeholder = 'Sélectionner une filiale';
        $all = 'Toutes les filiales';
        $filter = 'Filtrer les offres';
        break;

    case 'en':
        $placeholder = 'Select an affiliate';
        $all = 'All affiliates';
        $filter = 'Filter offers';
        break;

    case 'YOUR_LANGUAGE_CODE':
        $placeholder = 'YOUR TRANSLATION FOR PLACEHOLDER';
        $all = 'YOUR TRANSLATION FOR ALL';
        $filter = 'YOUR TRANSLATION FOR FILTER';
        break;
}
?>
```